# How can check app is game or not android?

Tags: android

I want to check app install in device is game or not?
I read in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#flags :
public static final int FLAG_IS_GAME
Value for flags : true if the application was declared to be a game, or false if it is a non-game application.
But I don't know the use.

Comment: no you cannot do that

Comment: I had the same task, and posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409568/how-to-list-all-apks-with-isgame-flag-set-to-true

Answer (score 0):

Shortly - you cannot do that because there's no such distinction. As for `FLAG_IS_GAME` - this is API21+

Comment: thanks, you can suggest for me solution to find app game . My device run kitkat version, but more app (from google play) can classify what app is game.

Comment: Checking from Google Play requires Internet and `FLAG_IS_GAME` is not a requirement for games.

Comment: FLAG_IS_GAME  is now deprecated as well, the answer you are looking for is here now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409568/how-to-list-all-apks-with-isgame-flag-set-to-true